# Installing custom driver on Win7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, device-driver

I'm trying to install a custom driver (`.sys`, virtual device) on Windows 7 64-bit, but I always get this error in Event Viewer:

> "The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load"
>   (EventID = 7026)

The driver is 64 bit and I install it by adding registry key to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\`, but I get same message whatever I try: signed/unsigned, copying it to `SysWOW64\drivers`, `System32\drivers` or both, installing it as admin or not...

Any idea what could generate this event error? Wouldn't the message be different if there is actual problem with driver's code? I'm almost sure that `.sys` file is good and that the problem is somewhere else.

Sorry if question doesn't provide enough information. I don't know what else could be relevant, but please let me know and I'll edit it.

Comment: When the OS starts up, did you press F8 to boot into Advanced Boot Options and disable driver signing checking?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've did that, but as it didn't work, I have continued trying with signed file.